# how to determine the starting byte of IP Header and TCP header in a raw packet

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, libpcap

I want to use libpcap to capture packets 
but since the length of ethernet header or 802.11 header may vary
and the length of IP header may also vary,
how can I determine the starting byte(pointer) of the IP Header and TCP header
besides, how to distinguish whether a packet is a pure IP packet, TCP packet or UDP packet?
are there any APIs or ways to do this?
thanks!

Comment: The length of an ethernet header cannot vary! At offset 14 you will find the IP packet, and then from there you can find the length of the IP header and add that to 14 to get the offset of the TCP header.

Comment: then how about the 802.11 header?

Comment: I've never seen one of those in a packet capture, and I'm not really familiar with it, but it does seem to have a fixed size (30 bytes + 4 bytes of trailer), so, also not a problem.

Comment: when i receive a packet, I have to judge what is the size of the 2nd-layer header, because it may be an ethernet header or 802.11 header.

Comment: But in a single capture file the packets are all of the same type, and [the header tells you which one it is](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html)!

Comment: No, 802.11 headers aren't all the same size; they might contain different numbers of MAC addresses, they might or might not have QoS information, etc..  See the 802.11 standard - or tcpdump's or Wireshark's code for parsing 802.11 headers - for details.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using libpcap, you can determine the size of link layer header, either by directly looking at the pcap file header (for offline captures) `pcap_file_header.linktype` or (for live and offline captures) from a call to `pcap_datalink()`. Most of the time this will be `LINKTYPE_ETHERNET`. To ensure a packet is IPv4, you can cast into an Ethernet header and check to ensure the ethertype is `ETHERTYPE_IP` (make sure you wrap it inside of `ntohs()`. I usually apply bpf filters to my pcap instantiations so I never worry about that stuff. To check the higher layer protocols however and assuming you're using `pcap_dispatch()`, you can write a callback as per the following: (the libnet library is still useful for its wide array of portable packet structures):

```
#include <libnet.h>
#include <pcap.h>

void
process_packet(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
    struct libnet_ipv4_hdr *ip;
    struct libnet_udp_hdr  *tcp;
    uint16_t ip_hl, udp_hl, header_cruft;

    ip     = (struct libnet_ipv4_hdr *)(packet + LIBNET_ETH_H);
    ip_hl  = ip->ip_hl << 2;

    switch (ip->ip_p)
    {
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            udp    = (struct libnet_udp_hdr *)(packet + LIBNET_ETH_H + ip_hl);
            udp_hl = tcp->th_off << 2;
            header_cruft = LIBNET_ETH_H + ip_hl + tcp_hl;
            break;
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            /** you get the idea */
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: If you're reading an offline capture with libpcap/WinPcap, `pcap_datalink()` will return the link-layer header type for the file, so you can use the same code for live capturing and reading capture files.

Comment: Note also that `pcap_datalink()` returns `DLT_` values, not `LINKTYPE_` values; in 99 44/100% of the cases, they have the same numerical value, but in some cases, they don't (some OSes use different numerical values for particular `DLT_` definitions, but that doesn't work in capture files, where the interpretation needs to be the same on all OSes).